# How to calculate sum * quantity using aggregate operators?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, aggregate

I'm working with a datagridview that contains BookNumber, Title, AuthorNum, Price and quantityInStock. I have to make a button that shows the total amount in inventory (sum of the price * quantity). I've already created a button that shows the cost of books here

```
   Dim totCost As Double = Aggregate r In BooksDataSet.tblBooks
                    Select r.Price Into Sum()
    MessageBox.Show("Total price for all Books is: " & totCost.ToString("c"))
```

but I'm unsure how I would do multiplication using aggregate. Any help would be appreciated. Here's part of the table I'm working with

```
BookNumber    Title     AuthorNum    Price    QuantityInStock
101       Garden of Eden      1      $35.99    15
146         Rosebud           1      $24.50    20
224        Cycle World        2      $15.99     5
```

Comment: show us an example with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
Dim totCost As Double = _
    Aggregate r In BooksDataSet.tblBooks _
    Select r.Price * r.QuantityInStock Into Sum()
MessageBox.Show("Total price for all Books is: " & totCost.ToString("c"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
Dim total = BooksDataSet.tblBooks.Sum(function(s) s.Price * s.QuantityInStock)
```